# Subdomain with index.shtml as default page?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, shtml

Is there a way to use a .shtml as the default page for a subdomain? I need it this way as my site uses HTML includes. Possibly add something in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your definition of virtual host this:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

You can find [more info in the apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming server-side includes are already enabled on your server (which is what the other answer is addressing), otherwise your site wouldn't already be able to use "HTML includes" as you say it does.

To set a `.shtml` file (eg. `index.shtml`) as the default page for a subdomain then you'd set the appropriate `DirectoryIndex` in the `.htaccess` file in the root of the subdomain. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.shtml
```

Comment: I have tried this and it did not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Is the URL you are requesting of the form: `https://subdomain.example.com/`? What actually happens when you request this URL? What is the `.shtml` file you wish to set as the default? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: Yes, the URL is https://qm.exploreloudoncounty.com/. I receive a Content Encoding Error when accessing it. I tried changing the file to index.html and it will load, just not correctly obviously because it needs to be index.shtml to display the server-side includes. I tried including index.shtml and index.html together, and only index.shtml, after DirectoryIndex in the .htaccess.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Apache I'm on - how do I find out?

Comment: Does it work if you request `sub.example.com/index.shtml` directly?  (Although I tried that with the URL you gave and that didn't appear to work either?) Curious, requesting `/<non-existent-file>` results in a 500 error? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Is it only requests to the document root of the subdomain that you want to serve this particular file? Or requests for any directory? You could use mod_rewrite instead to internally rewrite the request and not reply on mod_dir (ie. DirectoryIndex).